# Xamarin.Forms UWP - Launch app on login

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to launch my app when the user logs in to Windows. I have the appropriate `Extension` (`StartupTask`) set in *Package.appxmanifest*, and I can get the app to launch when I log in to Windows, as expected. However, the app crashes after showing the Splash screen for about a second or two.

In my *App.xaml.cs* file, I have overridden the `OnLaunched` (called when the user launches the app) and `OnActivated` (called when the system launches the app after Windows login). Both call the same function to initialize my app; however, the app crashes only when the app is initialized from the `OnActivated` function. When initialized from `OnLaunched`, it works as expected. Here is the relevant code, from *App.xaml.cs*:

```
// Called when the user launches the app
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Calling InitializeApp here, the app launches without problem
    InitializeApp(e);
}

// Called when the system launches the app after Windows login
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);
    // Calling InitializeApp here will cause the app to crash
    InitializeApp((LaunchActivatedEventArgs)e);
}

// initialize the app
async void InitializeApp(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

        var assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>()
        {
            typeof(CachedImage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
            typeof(CachedImageRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
        };
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
        // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
        // parameter
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
    }

    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();

    if (session == null)
    {
        // prevent the app from stopping when minimized
        session = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
        session.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified;
        session.Revoked += (s, a) => { };
        var result = await session.RequestExtensionAsync();

        if (result == ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EXTENDED EXECUTION DENIED");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it just crash without anything else or is there an exception thrown?

Comment: @Johannes Because the OnActivated function is only called when the app launches after logging into Windows, I haven't figured out a way to debug it and see what exactly is going on. Though after commenting out line by line and logging out of windows/logging in again, I found it crashes at the Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init() call, which MartinZikmund also mentioned below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to cast the `IActivatedEventArgs` to `LaunchActivatedEventArgs`, but when startup activation happens, the type is actually `StartupTaskActivatedEventArgs`.

Luckily, you actually need the `e` parameter only for `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init` which actually accepts `IActivatedEventArgs`, so you can just change the parameter of `InitializeApp` to be `IActivatedEventArgs` and remove the cast to `LaunchActivatedEventArgs` in `OnActivated`.

Comment: Concerning the line `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);`, the `IActivatedEventArgs` interface doesn't have a property `Arguments`, so will providing an empty string instead cause any issues?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed that. If you don't use secondary tiles, command line arguments or toast notification arguments, you can simply remove this and just use the `Navigate` overload with one parameter.

Comment: If you decide to use one of these, you can always for example add a second parameter to the `IinitializeApp` method, that would either contain these arguments or be empty.

Comment: As of right now I'm not using any of those functions. I updated the code, and it doesn't crash now, awesome. And that is a good idea about providing an a second parameter for the arguments, it should completely solve this issue. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it helps :-) , happy coding!